# Convolution with delta function

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

I am merely looking for the result of the convolution of a function and a delta function. 
I know there is some sort of identity but I can't seem to find it.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u-x)\delta(u-a)du=?$

Answer (score 15):

It's called the [sifting property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-a)\,dx=f(a).
$$

Now, if
$$
f(t)*g(t):=\int_0^t f(t-s)g(s)\,ds,
$$
we want to compute
$$
f(t)*\delta(t-a)=\int_0^t f(t-s)\delta(s-a)\,ds.
$$
With an eye on the sifting property above (which requires that we integrate "across the spike" of the Dirac delta, which occurs at $a$, we consider two cases.

1. If $t<a$, then $\delta(s-a)\equiv 0$ since $0\le s\le t<a$. Therefore $\int_0^t f(t-s)\delta(s-a)\,ds\equiv 0$.
2. If $t\geq a$, then by the sifting property, $\int_0^t f(t-s)\delta(s-a)\,ds=f(t-s)\Big|_{s=a}=f(t-a)$.

Thus,
\begin{align}
f(t)*\delta(t-a)=\int_0^t f(t-s)\delta(s-a)\,ds&=\begin{cases} 0, &t<a,\\ f(t-a) &t\ge a,\end{cases}=f(t-a)u(t-a),
\end{align}
where $u(t)$ denotes the unit step function.

Comment: This appears to conflict with the [result on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation) as well as what I have seen in a number of places, where $f(t) * \delta(t - a) = f(t - a)$.

Comment: Ah whoops, I just noticed you are defining a unilateral convolution. Sorry! Though the questioner did ask about bilateral, so worth leaving this comment I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

The delta "function" is the multiplicative identity of the convolution algebra. That is, $$\int f(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau=\int f(t-\tau)\delta(\tau)d\tau=f(t)$$
This is essentially the definition of $\delta$: the distribution with integral $1$ supported only at $0$.