# How to apply AM to a signal

Tags: signal-processing

i am trying to understand how amplitude modulation works; i have already understood that it is given by the following:

$$AM (f(t)) = cos2πτt * f(t),$$

where τ is the frequency of the sinusoid.

So for example, if i were given a function like:

$$f(t) = 100sin(100t) + 350sin(350t)$$

modulated in amplitude by the following:

$$cos200πt$$

What would the result be? I can't seem to be able to put all the pieces together.

What i've tried to do is to calculate the frequency for the cos function and put it inside the formula, however i don't know if it's the proper thing to do, and if it is, i don't know how to continue!

Does anyone know what's the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: do you know the correspondance of multiplication in the time domain, at the frequency domain?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören do you mean the fourier trasform of a convolution?

Comment: yes. convolution at the Fourier domain. so what is the Fourier of a sine or cosine function?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören sin would be 1/2i[δ(f-A) -δ(f+A)]. Cos would be similar but without the i at the denom and with a + insead of - between the deltas. Is what i’ve stated correct?

Comment: Be careful that one of the frequencies are negative and in reality cannot be realized. Whatever, yes, at the frequency domain we get a dirac delta function. now consider convolving ANY function with a dirac delta. what happens?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören i’m not entirely sure about this, so i could definitely be wrong, but would we get a sifted signal?

Comment: yes exactly. have a look at this for mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015498/convolution-with-delta-function  just the answer with 3 upvotes and put $a=0$.

Comment: look at here. you will see what I am talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören thank you, this clarified a lot!